# Angular Ionic Parsing/Displaying Data based from another Data

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to display a data (Date) that is based to another data (Order status).

This is the current output which is wrong because it displays all the dates on each order. The certain date must be only printed on each order not all.

[image]

Here is my .ts code

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService, private http: HttpClient) {
  this.data = '';
  this.error = '';
 }

public statuses = [];
public dates = [];

private prepareDataRequest(): Observable<any> {  // <-- change return type here
  // Define the data URL
  const dataUrl = '';
  // Prepare the request
  return this.http.get(dataUrl);
}

ionViewWillEnter() {
  // Load the data
  this.prepareDataRequest().subscribe(
    data => {
      // Set the data to display in the template
      this.statuses = data.output.Result.partsOrderTrackingListSequence
        .map(item => {
          if (item.status && item.status !== '') {
            return item.status;
          } else {
            return '-';
          }
        });
        this.dates = data.output.Result.partsOrderTrackingListSequence
        .map(item => {

          if (item.date && item.date !== '') {
            return item.date;
          } else {
            return '-';
          }
        });
    },
    err => {
      // Set the error information to display in the template
      this.error = `An error occurred, the data could not be retrieved: Status: ${err.status}, Message: ${err.statusText}`;
    }
  );
}
```

My page.html code

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!error; else errorContent">
    <p *ngFor="let status of statuses let status of dates">
      {{ status }} - {{dates}}
    </p>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #errorContent>
    <p>
      <span style="color: red;">{{error}}</span>
    </p>
  </ng-template>
```

Apologies I'm new in Angular and Typescript and I'm trying to browse and search to the guides available but no luck. If you can give me any good tutorials/guide links about parsing and displaying JSON data to Angular Ionic pages and also for changing the display format for the date. It will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz instance ? Or Either add the data returned by the API's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to modify your `ionViewWillEnter() function`

```
OrderList= [];
ionViewWillEnter() {
  // Load the data
  this.prepareDataRequest().subscribe(
    data => {
      // Takes data into in single Array and print 
      this.OrderList = data.output.Result.partsOrderTrackingListSequence


    },
    err => {
      // Set the error information to display in the template
      this.error = `An error occurred, the data could not be retrieved: Status: ${err.status}, Message: ${err.statusText}`;
    }
  );
}
```

Then in HTML

```
<ng-container *ngIf=""!error; else errorContent"">
    <p *ngFor=""let order of OrderList;"">
      {{ order.status }} - {{order.dates}}
    </p>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #errorContent>
    <p>
      <span style=""color: red;"">{{error}}</span>
    </p>
  </ng-template>
```

Comment: Pls. check now i have updated my answer there is small bracket error.

Comment: Hi, is there any way to add ApiKey? because I'm using my API link under the Data url and it requires api key to access

Comment: What kind of key ?
Does it like token to http call with your network call ?

Comment: Its a key so that I can access the API but its okay now I just replaced prepareDataRequest() method to my GetRemoteData() which I used at first to test the connection in console logs. Thanks! :)

Comment: How to display the specific value of my order status? {{order?.status == ORDER PROCESSED}} is this the correct format?

Answer (score 1):

Extract the values from the observable in a single array-like structure instead of separate arrays. Use this array in the template for data binding with valid values.

**Template file:**

```
// Array which will have the values of orders.
orders= [];
ionViewWillEnter() {
  // Load the data
  this.prepareDataRequest().subscribe(
    data => {
      // Takes data into in single Array and print 
      this.orders = data.output.Result.partsOrderTrackingListSequence;
    },
    err => {
      // Set the error information to display in the template
      this.error = `An error occurred, the data could not be retrieved: Status: ${err.status}, Message: ${err.statusText}`;
    }
  );
}
```

**Template file**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!error; else errorContent">
    <p *ngFor="let order of orders">
      {{ order?.status || '-' }} - {{order?.date || '' }}
    </p>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #errorContent>
    <p>
      <span style="color: red;">{{error}}</span>
    </p>
  </ng-template>
```